# Why do people crouch in CS:S?

Tags: counter-strike-source

While playing CS:S, I noticed that quite a few people would crouch when in a firefight. Is there any reason for this, like to reduce your hitbox or to reduce recoil from a weapon? I'm assuming the former, but of course to assume is to make an a** out of you and me. I've also heard about hitbox issues, does crouching take advantage of one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Crouching offers several benefits:

1. smaller surface area to shoot at.
2. increases accuracy and reduces the recoil.
3. a moving target is harder to hit. (crouching during/immediately before a fight or through bunny hopping)
4. moving while crouched produces less sound.

Comment: A stationary target is easier to hit, so when you crouch, wouldn't you be easier to hit and thus a disadvantage?

Comment: I'd say it's a tradeoff.  Easier to hit if you already have a clear line of fire, harder to hit if they have cover and keep on the move (presumably they are crouching and walking, not just crouching)

Comment: Even then, they would still be moving slower if they are crouched. The third point really shouldn’t be included in that list.

Comment: your opponent is likely aiming for your face, crouching before he fires makes it so he is aiming at nothing. Your opponent then has to readjust their aim to target the new location of your face.

Comment: This is also why you see bunny-hopping frequently used where there is no cover to take from crouching.  Jumping/crouching is the fastest way to move the position of your head.

Comment: You've forgotten tea bagging, but that is usually after an encounter.

Comment: Also, when not in a firefight, moving while crouched produces less sound.

Comment: @Nigralbus Thanks, I had forgotten to mention that. Now included in my answer.

Comment: @Nigralbus So does walking, which is faster. I'm sorry, but this answer makes it out as if crouching is actually a good strategic decision. Watch a professional match and see how often the players spend crouching in a firefight- it's basically never.

Comment: @Decency Worrying about pro level strategies would be silly as they often are better at certain mechanics than other players (ACCURACY, especially while moving). For beginner players (the question asker) the accuracy improvement/position change for crouching can likely result in a kill vs another beginner player. This answer is simply a list of mechanical benefits and does not address when they should be used.

Comment: @ColinD Sure, I agree. But the question is "why do people crouch" and the real answer is "because they can't control their aim while strafing properly". Not a big deal, but definitely seems misleading to me.

Answer (score 5):

If cover is available, crouching allows for less exposure of a hitbox.

I'm not sure about CS:S specifically, but in many FPSes, there is a tradeoff of speed, but also a further benefit of getting your head quickly out of sight, so as to avoid snipers. And I believe CS:S is one game wherein you can crouch-jump, so it is even beneficial to crouch when moving, to help clear higher levels of elevation.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, crouching is a last-resort measure when you're too close in a firefight or too cornered to otherwise gain any real evasion from moving around. If you turn a corner, for example, and run into someone, immediately crouching can give you the edge while he fires his initial shots over your head.

If you have any room to strafe, that's almost always preferable than crouching and spraying. Many professionals advise that new players actually unbind their crouch key to prevent them from getting in a habit of crouching and spraying when put into difficult situations.